# Building Html in Html Helper using Razor or Tag builder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I am building a Html Helper in MVC 4 and I want to know how to build tags / html in the html helpers properly.

For example here is simple html helper that creates image tag using `TagBuilder` class:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper html, string imagePath, 
    string title = null, string alt = null)
{
    var img = new TagBuilder("img");
    img.MergeAttribute("src", imagePath);
    if (title != null) img.MergeAttribute("title", title);
    if (alt != null) img.MergeAttribute("alt", alt);

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(img.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
}
```

From another side I can do something like this:

```
// C#:
public static MvcHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper html, string imagePath, 
    string title = null, string alt = null)
{
    var model = new SomeModel() {
        Path = imagePath,
        Title = title,
        Alt = alt
    };

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(Razor.Parse("sometemplate.cshtml", model));
}

// cshtml:
<img src="@model.Path" title="@model.Title" alt="@model.Alt" />
```

Which is the better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are valid, I would suspect the latter to be much slower however and I'm trying to see what benefits it would have over using a Partial View.

My rule of thumb is that HtmlHelpers should only be used for simple markup; anything more complicated should be using Partial Views and Child Actions.

Comment: I asked this question because I have very complicated helper that builds an table. To build the table I using huge number of tags so I want to know if it will much slower or slower because it can very help me.

Comment: I would have put that in the question as building the HTML for a table is more complicated than your given example. For building tables you should take a look at MvcContrib's Grid helper - http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid or at the WebGrid in System.Web.Helpers - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx. I wouldn't reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: I thought that too but it isn't what I needed. I'm not displaying data from DB or something like this... So can you please help me get the correct answer for my question?

Comment: The grid helpers above don't have to be used with a data source, they work with any `IEnumerable<T>`. The question above only asks whether to use `TagBuilder` or `Razor.Parse()` to generate HTML. It sounds like you have a more specific question, I would edit this one to better clarify it.

Comment: @Russ_Cam My question is what situations I should perefer `TagBuilder` and what situations I should perefer `Razor.Parse`.

Answer (score 0):

The first method operates on strings in memory and is performing, the latter is more expensive in terms of resources and makes a file access.

Comment: I know the difference but I want to know what situations I should perefer `TagBuilder` and what situations I should perefer `Razor.Parse`