# Create a Template for DisplayNameFor method in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating a Asp.net MVC Site for the first type.

I'm creating a Details page, and used something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.MyProp)
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MyProp)
    </li>
<ul>
```

And I get something like that:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        MyProp
        MyPropValue
    </li>
<ul>
```

I'd like my field header and my field value to be wrapped inside individual Span's, so i can format it in a global css, like that:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="field-label">MyProp</span>
        <span class="field-value">MyPropValue</span>
    </li>
<ul>
```

I'd like to find a way to do that without having to enclose every field in a span. I get to solve that for DisplayFor method using a DisplayTemplate, but know i need to do that for DisplayNameFor, in a way that every time i use this Method it generates the span automatically.

I thought about creating my own substitute method for @Html.DisplayNameFor, but I'm a little confused about what would be the signature for that method.

Anybody got any tip on how to achieve that?

---

Edit: I tried creating a HtmlHelper extension method, like bellow:

```
public static IHtmlString OxDisplayNameFor<TModel, TField> (this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TField>> expression)
{
    return new HtmlString(String.Format(
        "<span class='display-label'>{0}</span>", "XXX"));
}
```

The only thing that remains is: How do i get the value from the expression parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature would be the same as for [`Html.DisplayNameFor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833706(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
public static MvcHtmlString DisplayWithDisplayNameFor<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{
    // construct a span tag and put html.DisplayNameFor(expression) in it
    // then another span tag and put html.DisplayFor(expression) in it
    // return all that
}
```

It would be more convenient to have it as a `@helper`, but you [cannot have a generic helper](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4760783/11683) and so cannot pass the property-pointing lambdas to it, so the closest you can do is something like:

```
@helper DisplayWithDisplayName(MvcHtmlString DisplayName, MvcHtmlString DisplayValue)
{
    <span class="field-label">@DisplayName</span>
    <span class="field-value">@DisplayValue</span>
}
```

which you would then call as

```
@DisplayWithDisplayNameFor(Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.MyProp), Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MyProp))
```

Comment: thanks. The method content was: return new HtmlString(String.Format("<span class='display-label'>{0}</span>", helper.DisplayNameFor(expression).ToString()));  Is it the best way?

Comment: @Marlon No, I would use `TagBuilder` (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/18214347/11683).